# How to get path to SYSTEM user %APPDATA% folder?

Tags: winapi

SHGetFolderPath returns %APPDATA% of user running the program even if it was called with the SYSTEM user token.

Comment: *"The [LocalSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localsystem-account) account is not associated with any logged-on user account."* It's unclear what you are trying to ultimately accomplish, but this sure reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @IInspectable - and so what ? anyway `SHGetFolderPath` return correct `AppData` path for LocalSystem token, if call it correct

Comment: @rbm: Since you apparently know, how to *"call it correct"*, why not leave an answer illustrating that?

Comment: @IInspectable - because question is unclear for me. if we call `SHGetFolderPath` with *LocalSystem* token for say `CSIDL_APPDATA` - it return something like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming` - not view any problems here. OP not show self code. also possible call `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUserW` with system token for `%APPDATA%`

Comment: why OP got wrong result i can not know. may be he fail open *LocalSystem* token and pass 0 in place token (without check this). this can explain result. but without view any code - this is only guess

Comment: Please show how exactly you proceed to _"call it with the SYSTEM user token"_. You may [edit]  your question.

Comment: @IInspectable, about problem: I would like the installer create file config for service.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for for me if run elevated:

```
// Compile with –DPSAPI_VERSION=1
#pragma comment(lib, "userenv.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <UserEnv.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <vector>

bool EnablePrivilege(WCHAR *szPrivName, bool enable)
{
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
  LUID  id;
  HANDLE    token;
  if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(0, szPrivName, &id))
    return false;
  if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &token))
    return false;
  tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
  tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = enable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;
  tp.Privileges[0].Luid.LowPart = id.LowPart;
  tp.Privileges[0].Luid.HighPart = id.HighPart;
  AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), 0, 0);
  CloseHandle(token);
  return (GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS);
}

bool IsTokenSystem(HANDLE tokenHandle)
{
  bool result = false;
  DWORD retLen = 0;
  DWORD tokenLen = 1024;
  std::vector<WCHAR> buf(tokenLen);
  TOKEN_USER *token = (TOKEN_USER*)&buf.front();
  if (GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle, TokenUser, token, tokenLen, &retLen)) {
    WCHAR *stringSid = 0;
    if (ConvertSidToStringSid(token->User.Sid, &stringSid))
      if (wcscmp(stringSid, L"S-1-5-18") == 0) // SYSTEM user SID
        result = true;
    LocalFree(stringSid);
    }
  return result;
}

HANDLE GetSystemProcessToken()
{
  if (!EnablePrivilege(SE_DEBUG_NAME, true))
    printf("Enable SeDebugPrivilege error: %d\n", GetLastError());
  DWORD pids[10000] = { 0 };
  DWORD needed = 0;
  if (!EnumProcesses(pids, sizeof(pids), &needed)) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (DWORD i = 0; i < needed / sizeof(DWORD); ++i) {
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pids[i]);
    if (!processHandle)
      continue;
    HANDLE tokenHandle = 0;
    DWORD access = TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_EXECUTE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_READ;
    if (OpenProcessToken(processHandle, access, &tokenHandle)) {
      if (IsTokenSystem(tokenHandle)) {
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return tokenHandle;
      }
    }
    CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
  }
  return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR * argv[])
{
  HANDLE systemToken = GetSystemProcessToken();
  if (systemToken == 0)
    printf("Can't get systemToken\n");
  WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
  if (SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, systemToken, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, &path[0]) == S_OK) {
    printf("AppData folder: %ls\n", &path[0]);
  } else {
    printf("SHGetFolderPath error: %d\n", GetLastError());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error handling is wrong. Every single call to `GetLastError` is invoked at a time, where it doesn't return a meaningful value. Plus, as `try` block that strictly contains function calls, that never throw C++ exceptions. May want to rework that.